# Could anyone explain this grammar question for me?

Tags: grammar, universal-grammar

According to the grammar rule i have learned up to now, in Arabic people use the feminine form of adjective to describe plural noun (more than two).For instance,دفاتر كشيرة（many books),here we use feminine adjective  كشيرة to describe plural noun دفاتر.But recently i also find another sentence "طالبات جديدات”(many new female students),why not say "طالبات جديدة'??

Comment: It should say كثيرة

Comment: This question looks more about usage then Linguistics.

Answer (score 2):

You use plural adjectives (masculine or feminine) with plural nouns designating people, but feminine singular adjectives with nouns designating things.